# Concatenate 2D arrays with different first dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have three numpy arrays, respectively with shape:

```
x1 = (30, 17437)
x2 = (30, 24131)
x3 = (30, 19782)
```

I would like to concatenate them and create a numpy array of dimension `(30, 61350)`. I tried with

```
labels = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3))
```

but I got the error:

> all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 17437 and the array at index 1 has size 24131

Comment: This is a poorly posed question `x1 = (30, 17437)`, as in the accepted answer, is not a numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as shown below:

```
labels = np.array([x1[0], (x1[1] + x2[1] + x3[1])])
print(labels)
```

**Output:**

```
[   30 61350]
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to specify the `axis` along which the arrays will be joined. This issue is fixed easily:

```py
labels = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.r_`:

```
x1 = np.zeros((30, 17437))
x2 = np.zeros((30, 24131))
x3 = np.zeros((30, 19782))
np.r_['-1',x1,x2,x3]
```

Check:

```
>>> np.r_['-1',x1,x2,x3].shape
(30, 61350)
```